# How can I stop big windows from resizing when I lock my workstation?

Tags: windows-xp, multiple-monitors

I have a multimonitor setup on Windows XP x64.

If I have a window sized to be larger than a single monitor (say, a web browser that's wide enough for 2 monitors), and I lock my workstation, it will be resized down to a single monitor when I unlock the workstation.

Is there any way to stop this behavior?

Comment: I've tried this, and I have the same behavior... never noticed that before! I think this is a windows bug. Maybe you should file a bug report (http://www.microsoft.com/globaldev/outreach/feedback/feedback.mspx) ;-)

Comment: Wow, I was just thinking about this the other day with my workstation at work. Great question!

Comment: +1 for the question. I have the same issue under Windows XP when using the Sysinternals Desktop.

Comment: If your window is small enough for one display, but you have it spanning both, it will move the window (un-resized) to one monitor after unlock.  Same behavior on XP.  I tried the most up-to-date drivers for the graphics card, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a driver problem. I had a similar problem with an old laptop. No external display, but there was still one listed in the display properties, set to a low resolution. Whenever I closed the lid of my laptop, any windows were shrunk, possibly to the size of the ghost display.

If found the fix here: http://blog.benday.com/archive/2006/09/19/14927.aspx

It doesn't sound like the same problem, but this may be another clue to the mystery!

Answer (score 0):

I have this too on Vista. My laptop resolution is 1366x768 and I have a monitor attached at 1680x1050. When I shut the lid and resume, the windows are technically maximised, but on the laptop screen the window starts showing the borders, as if it was a unmaximised window dragged to that size. On the second monitor, the window is the size of my laptop screen, not the full size of the monitor. This image shows what I mean:

[image]

I posted on the UltraMon forums (believing it to be a bug in UltraMon) and the only advice I managed to get was it could be caused by a service called TMM:

> Some people reported that this issue was caused by TMM, a service installed on Vista, you can disable it under Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Task Scheduler > Microsoft > Windows > MobilePC.

Unfortunately this didn't work for me, and I've seen other threads where people simply say "it's a Windows bug". So there's not anything you can do AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried minimizing the window before you lock the workstation? I am not sure if that will work in your case, but it does work with programs that default to a lower resolution.

Comment: Not sure what that'd get me. When I unlock the workstation i have to remaximize the window. So if I minimize it, I'd still have to remaximize it.